# Open or set focus to a specific tab with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, setfocus

I have an html document with three links to different apps.

If I click `link#1` the `#1`-app will open in a new tab. In the new tab the same links are available (but the link to the active app is disabled. If I now click `link#2` the `#2`-app will open in a new app.

Now if I click the `link#1`, from within `app#2`, I would like to set focus to the tab with the `#1`-app instead of opening another tab with the `#1`-app.

Is this possible?

I know this could somehow be done with using new windows but is it possible with tabs? An acceptable workaround can be to set focus on a hidden field within the different apps. I know that this may be intrusive but it is called for in this situation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you checked this, http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: Sorry but no code to show. I have not tried anything (except for searching for a solution). I'm not a coder, I'm asking to find out if this is possible at all since I would like to use this approach. Someone else will have to code it if it is possible to achieve. 


Sorry if I was unclear in my original post, but I'm not talking about tabs within a web page. I'm talking about tabs in the browser.